# Getting implicit scala Numeric from Azavea Numeric

Tags: scala, generics, numeric

I am using the Azavea Numeric Scala library for generic maths operations. However, I cannot use these with the Scala Collections API, as they require a scala Numeric and it appears as though the two Numerics are mutually exclusive. Is there any way I can avoid re-implementing all mathematical operations on Scala Collections for Azavea Numeric, apart from requiring all types to have context bounds for both Numerics?

```
import Predef.{any2stringadd => _, _}

class Numeric {
  def addOne[T: com.azavea.math.Numeric](x: T) {
    import com.azavea.math.EasyImplicits._
    val y = x + 1 // Compiles

    val seq = Seq(x)
    val z = seq.sum // Could not find implicit value for parameter num: Numeric[T]
  }
}
```

Where Azavea Numeric is defined as

```
trait Numeric[@scala.specialized A] extends java.lang.Object with 

com.azavea.math.ConvertableFrom[A] with com.azavea.math.ConvertableTo[A] with scala.ScalaObject {
   def abs(a:A):A
   ...remaining methods redacted...
}

object Numeric {
  implicit object IntIsNumeric extends IntIsNumeric
  implicit object LongIsNumeric extends LongIsNumeric
  implicit object FloatIsNumeric extends FloatIsNumeric
  implicit object DoubleIsNumeric extends DoubleIsNumeric
  implicit object BigIntIsNumeric extends BigIntIsNumeric
  implicit object BigDecimalIsNumeric extends BigDecimalIsNumeric

  def numeric[@specialized(Int, Long, Float, Double) A:Numeric]:Numeric[A] = implicitly[Numeric[A]]
}
```

Comment: "apart from requiring all types to have context bounds for both Numerics?" What is wrong with this approach?

Comment: In our particular scenario, the code in question has a significant hierarchy above it, so looking to avoid contaminating a large number of classes with Scala Numeric context bounds. In addition, the naming clash means that the external API becomes more cluttered with the fully qualified names, and fundamentally Azavea Numeric should be an extension of Scala Numeric, instead of an alternative.

Comment: that doesn't make any sense...

Comment: Sorry, for some reason it only showed me the first few words of your comment

Comment: I don't know how `com.azavea.math.Numeric` is defined, but if it provides the same functionality as Scala's Numeric, there should be a way to convert one to the other. You should post `com.azavea.math.Numeric`s definition.

Comment: I don't think it would be appropriate to post the full 427 line definition of com.azavea.math.Numeric here. From the source it does not appear as though conversion methods are present - so I'm guessing my question is whether there is a way of getting hold of scala.math.Numeric evidence without context bounds, given we know that we are dealing with numeric classes.

Comment: by definition I just meant the interface, not the implementation.

Comment: if you have the specific (e.g. Int) type, you can always do `implicitly[Numeric[Int]]`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18717/discussion-between-woodz-and-kim-stebel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most general solution would be to write a class that wraps `com.azavea.math.Numeric` and implements `scala.math.Numeric` in terms of it:

```
class AzaveaNumericWrapper[T]( implicit val n: com.azavea.math.Numeric[T] ) extends scala.math.Numeric {
  def compare (x: T, y: T): Int = n.compare(x, y)
  def minus (x: T, y: T): T = n.minus(x, y)
  // and so on
}
```

Then implement an implicit conversion:

```
// NOTE: in scala 2.10, we could directly declare AzaveaNumericWrapper as an implicit class
implicit def toAzaveaNumericWrapper[T]( implicit n: com.azavea.math.Numeric[T] ) = new AzaveaNumericWrapper( n )
```

The fact that `n` is itself an implicit is key here: it allows for implicit values of type `com.azavea.math.Numeric` to be automatically used where na implicit value of 
type `scala.math.Numeric` is expected.
Note that to be complete, you'll probably want to do the reverse too (write a class ScalaNumericWrapper that implements com.azavea.math.Numeric in terms of scala.math.Numeric).

Now, there is a disadvantage to the above solution: you get a conversion (and thus an instanciation) on each call (to a method that has a context bound of type `scala.math.Numeric`, and where you only an instance of `com.azavea.math.Numeric` is in scope).
So you will actually want to define an implicit singleton instance of AzaveaNumericWrapper for each of your numeric type. Assuming that you have types `MyType` and `MyOtherType` for which you defined instances of `com.azavea.math.Numeric`:

```
implicit object MyTypeIsNumeric extends AzaveaNumericWrapper[MyType]
implicit object MyOtherTypeIsNumeric extends AzaveaNumericWrapper[MyOtherType]
//...
```

Also, keep in mind that the apparent main purpose of azavea's Numeric class is to greatly enhance execution speed (mostly due to type parameter specialization). 
Using the wrapper as above, you lose the specialization and hence the speed that comes out of it. Specialization has to be used all the way down, 
and as soon as you call a generic method that is not specialized, you enter in the world of unspecialized generics (even if that method then calls back a specialized method).
So in cases where speed matters, try to use azavea's `Numeric` directly  instead of scala's `Numeric` (just because AzaveaNumericWrapper uses it internally 
does not mean that you will get any speed increase, as specialization won't happen here).

You may have noticed that I avoided in my examples to define  instances of `AzaveaNumericWrapper` for types `Int`, `Long` and so on.
This is because there are already (in the standard library) implicit values of scala.math.Numeric for these types.
You might be tempted to just hide them (via something like `import scala.math.Numeric.{ShortIsIntegral  => _}`), so as to be sure that your own (azavea backed) version is used, 
but there is no point. The only reason I can think of would be to make it run faster, but as explained above, it wont.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Régis Jean-Gilles solution, which is a good one, and wrap Azavea's Numeric. You can also try recreating the methods yourself, but using Azavea's Numeric. Aside from NumericRange, most should be pretty straightforward to implement.

You may be interested in [Spire](https://github.com/non/spire) though, which succeeds Azavea's Numeric library. It has all the same features, but some new ones as well (more operations, new number types, sorting & selection, etc.). If you are using 2.10 (most of our work is being directed at 2.10), then using Spire's Numeric eliminates virtually all overhead of a generic approach and often runs as fast as a direct (non-generic) implementation.

That said, I think your question is a good suggestion; we should really add a `toScalaNumeric` method on Numeric. Which Scala collection methods were you planning on using? Spire adds several new methods to Arrays, such as qsum, qproduct, qnorm(p), qsort, qselect(k), etc.

Comment: Thanks for introducing Spire as a potential replacement to Azavea Numeric. Is Azavea Numeric no longer in active development or is Spire an alternative? I was initially looking to just use Seq.sum, but this has allowed us to use all the numeric based methods.

Comment: The author of Azavea's Numeric library (Erik Osheim) and I created Spire, which we are actively developing and replaces Azavea's Numeric library. Spire's feature set is much larger than Azavea's and works with 2.10, but Azavea's comes with a compiler plugin for 2.9 that does what we now do with macros in 2.10. So, if you are stuck on 2.9 AND you use the plugin, then that could be a reason to not use Spire.

Comment: Hi Woodz, Erik and I added some support for these conversions. The idea is that you can import scala.math.compat._ and things should just work. If not, you may need to use, eg, scala.math.compat.numeric[A] directly. This will be part of 0.3.0, which we are releasing soon :-) Thanks for the suggestion.  https://github.com/non/spire/commit/5eac52f79cd3d5317fc2a6faac85f0d17fce39bb

Comment: Oops, that's spire.math.compat (not scala). Sorry for the confusion.